# Calculate the value given several percentiles and their values

Tags: statistics, percentile

On a particular test whose scores are distributed normally, the 2nd percentile is 1,720, while the 84th percentile is 1,990. What score, rounded to the nearest 10, most closely corresponds to the 16th percentile?

(A) 1,750
(B) 1,770
(C) 1,790
(D) 1,810
(E) 1,830

My answer is (1990-1720)/82 = 3.29, then 3.29*14 + 1720 = 1766.10, hence option B. But the answer is actually D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given information you have two equations:

$$\Phi\left( \frac{1720-\mu}{\sigma} \right)=0.02 ,\Phi\left( \frac{1990-\mu}{\sigma} \right)=0.84$$

Take the inverse function of $\Phi(z)$

$$ \frac{1720-\mu}{\sigma} =\Phi^{-1}\left(0.02\right) ,\frac{1990-\mu}{\sigma} =\Phi^{-1}\left(0.84\right)$$

$$ \frac{1720-\mu}{\sigma} =-2.054 , \frac{1990-\mu}{\sigma} =0.994$$

Now you have a small equation system with two variables and two equations which can be solved.

I get $\mu=1901.95$ and $\sigma=88.5827$

Then evaluate the value of $\Phi^{-1}(0.16)$. Since the standard normal distribution is symmetric around 0 we have $\Phi^{-1}(0.16)=-\Phi^{-1}(0.84)$

Finally the following equation has to be solved

$$\frac{x-1901.95}{88.5827}=-0.994$$

Comment: What does Φ(1720−μ)/σ mean and what is the function Φ?

Comment: @Hina $\Phi(z)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution. The function is symmetric around $0$ and it has an expected value of $0$ and a standard deviation of $1$. The table can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table). And with $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ you standardize a normal distributed variable $X$

Comment: Is there an alternative way to solve this problem without using the function of the standard normal distribution? This is actually a GRE question, I assume there is a less complex method to solve.

Comment: @Hina I don´t see a way to solve it without using the normal distribution. The question is referring to the normal distribution. I think it is required that you can handle exercises where the normal distribution is involved.